# Elasticsearch: search against _all field with boosting

Tags: elasticsearch

I am new to Elasticsearch.

I have the following mapping:

```
{
    "mappings": {

        "book": {

            "properties": {         
                "title": {
                    "properties": {
                        "en": {
                            "type": "string",
                            "analyzer": "standard"
                        },
                        "ar": {
                            "type": "string",
                            "analyzer": "standard"
                        }
                    }
                },

                "keyword": {
                    "properties": {
                        "en": {
                            "type": "string",
                            "analyzer": "standard"
                        },
                        "ar": {
                            "type": "string",
                            "analyzer": "standard"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

A sample document may have two languages for the same field of the same book. Here are two example documents:

```
{
    "title" : {
        "en": "hello",
        "ar": "مرحبا"
    },
    "keyword" : {
        "en": "world",
        "ar": "عالم"
    }   
}

{
    "title" : {
        "en": "Elasticsearch"
    },
    "keyword" : {
        "en": "full-text index"
    }   
}
```

Now I want to do a search against the _all field. Here is my query:

```
"query": { 
    "match" : {
        "_all" : {
            "query" : "hello",
            "operator" : "OR"
        }
    }
}
```

Is this correct mapping? One of the reasons that I want to use _all field instead of listing the specific fields in query is that I will include more languages.

The thing I am not sure about is how to add boost to the title.en, title.ar fields in the above query? Any better way of doing so in case of more languages?

Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that by using function_score query

```
{
   "query": {
      "function_score": {
         "functions": [
            {
               "boost_factor": "500",
               "filter": {
                  "term": {
                     "title.en": "hello"
                  }
               }
            },
            {
               "boost_factor": "200",
               "filter": {
                  "term": {
                     "title.ar": "hello"
                  }
               }
            }
         ],
         "query": {
            "match": {
               "_all": {
                  "query": "hello",
                  "operator": "OR"
               }
            }
         },
         "score_mode": "sum"
      }
   }
}
```

adding title.*

```
{
   "query": {
      "function_score": {
         "functions": [
            {
               "boost_factor": "500",
               "filter": {
                   "query": {
                      "query_string": {
                           "default_field": "title.*",
                            "query": "hello"
                       }
                   }
               }
            }
         ],
         "query": {
            "match": {
               "_all": {
                  "query": "hello",
                  "operator": "OR"
               }
            }
         },
         "score_mode": "sum"
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Siddardha Budige, thanks for providing a working solution! Is there any way that I can specify "title.*" instead of "title.en"? I will add more languages, and I dont want to change the query each time when a new language is added. Again, thanks!

Comment: @curious1 Yes, you can do that by specifying fields using wildcard. Small change you have to make in above query is to replace "term" query with "query_string".

Comment: Could you please update your answer with the title.* solution. I am new Elasticsearch and I am not sure about the right syntax for this. Maybe you can expand your answer by adding the "title.*" solution, which would be helpful to many people. Thank you!

Comment: @curious1 "title.*" solution added

Answer (score 1):

You should add this in the mapping:

```
_all" : {"enabled" : true}
```

For an example mapping check [this](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-all-field.html).

You can use _all field in your case as it is suitable for your requirement.
ElasticSearch Documentation states that:

> The idea of the _all field is that it includes the text of one or more
>   other fields within the document indexed. It can come very handy
>   especially for search requests, where we want to execute a search
>   query against the content of a document, without knowing which fields
>   to search on. This comes at the expense of CPU cycles and index size.

You are using a match query. It will work only if there is an exact match in _all field. By default, _all field is analyzed using standard analyzer. so a search for hello world using a match might won't return a hit. I'll advise in that case using a query_string or multi_match is much better. You can specify a custom analyser for _all field like:

```
"_all" : {"type" : "string", "analyzer" : "your_custom_analyzer"}
```

Thanks

Comment: dark_shadow, thanks for all info and advice. I did a test without changing my mapping. Match query does return the document (hello in title, and world in keyword) for "hello world". Did I miss anything? Anyway, I changed it to query_string, which seems provides a lot more options. Cannot say enough thank-you!

Comment: query_string is way more powerful than your expectation. You are doing it correct way. Thanks

Comment: I wanted to specify the _all field in the mapping as you said (type, analyzer). Should I add this specification in the properties section, together with my own fields? I cannot find an example for this. Just wanted to check with you.

Comment: Please check the link which I have given in my answer. It clearly shows an example. You need to declare it outside properties but inside book tag.

Comment: You mean put the type and analyzer specification for _all together with "_all" : {"enabled" : true} as in "_all" : {"enabled" : true, "type" : "string", ....}? Or I should have two "_all" entries under book tag? This is where I am confused. Thanks!